# echo different background-color

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have started to make some code, but I really do not know how to make my while loop, or if I am thinking right at all.

I have a formfield, where I can put in a number. That number is printed out in:

```
<div id="showsection">          
            <ul class="sectionnumbers" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px ;">
                <?php include('sections.php');?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Everytime I fx put in the number "0", it should get the background: "#81c77d", with a height on 20px; I have made the arrays for it, which I think is okay?

But how can I make my while loop for it?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include('session.php');

// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';
$voisins = array(0 => "#81c77d", 2 => "#81c77d", 3 => "#81c77d", 4 => "#81c77d", 7 => "#81c77d", 12 => "#81c77d", 15 => "#81c77d", 18 => "#81c77d", 19 => "#81c77d", 21 => "#81c77d", 22 => "#81c77d", 25 => "#81c77d", 26 => "#81c77d", 28 => "#81c77d", 29 => "#81c77d", 32 => "#81c77d", 35 => "#81c77d");
$jeu = array(0 => "#81e87c", 3 => "#81e87c", 12 => "#81e87c", 15 => "#81e87c", 26 => "#81e87c", 32 => "#81e87c", 35 => "#81e87c");
$orp_1 = array(6 => "#ffffff", 17 => "#ffffff", 34 => "#ffffff");
$tiers = array(5 => "#dfb07b", 8 => "#dfb07b", 10 => "#dfb07b", 11 => "#dfb07b", 13 => "#dfb07b", 16 => "#dfb07b", 23 => "#dfb07b", 24 => "#dfb07b", 27 => "#dfb07b", 30 => "#dfb07b", 33 => "#dfb07b", 36 => "#dfb07b");
$orp_2 = array(1 => "#ffffff", 9 => "#ffffff", 14 => "#ffffff", 20 => "#ffffff", 31 => "#ffffff");

// '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbertable ORDER BY num_id DESC LIMIT 27;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // gør variabler klar:    
    $number = null;    
    $n_id = null;

    /* bind result variabler */
    $stmt->bind_result($n_id, $number);

   /* fetch values for hver row, her kun 1 row dog: */
     while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            echo "<li><div style='background-color: ".$voisins."</li>";
            // loop through number and echo the background color of array


        }

     }  


// luk statement                        
    $stmt->close();

    // luk connection
    $mysqli->close();

echo "test";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick colors from color array by using an increamental variable like this:

**Your while loop:**

```
$i = 0; // initilize as 0
while ($stmt->fetch()) {


if ( !isset ($voisins[$i] )){
$i = 0; reinitilize if index null or offset color will repeat after last iteration.
}

 echo "<li><div style='background-color: ".$voisins[$i]."'></li>";


// loop through number and echo the background color of array
    $i++; 

}
```

**Note that:**
You have an error in your html you forgot to close the style quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot or the answer. When I try to run the code I get this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 10

Comment: Becuase u have more records than to array @m375

Comment: Can u repeat the colors ? @m375 after last color will repeat again

Comment: So I have to echo all variables before?

Comment: @m375 no.. after last color or array u want to repeat from the ist color?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The colours should follow the numbers there is in the array. I have a div tag, with a height: 300px width: 50px. When you put in a number it is going in the top of the array, with a height on 10px; . When you put in the next number, the former should jump a little down, so there is place for next number.

Comment: hm I do not know if I am talking black, it is a little bit hard to explain i think. But the main point is, when a specifik number is put in the form field, it should give me a specifik background-color based on my array.

Comment: Your table ids are equal to array key? @m375 ?

Comment: It should go in my div tag there is in the question

Comment: I get the errors: Undefined offset: 6 / 8 / 10 etc

I will try to google it

Comment: you can't anwser the OP's question right now there is no enough information to solve the problem...

Comment: Than just pass the id in array where I have use $i. @m375

Comment: I will look at it, and then get back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aaronxx yes u r right answer is only related to what he want OP didnt provide these information that he explain in comments.

Comment: Ah yeah of course Devpro. That make sence, it is working. Thanks a lot for the help. Then it could be solved anyways ...... ;-)

Comment: Yes I just thinking about id that u get from db.. its good to knw this solve yur issue @m375